# Using ngDialog in directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to make working ngDialog downloaded from here: [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.2.3/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
```

My directive:

```
directives = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngDialog']);
directives.directive('caseList', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel, ngDialog) {
    ......
     ngDialog.open({
                    template: '<p>my template</p>',
                    plain: true
                });
```

I am getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
Checking ngDialog object and it is undefined.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here what was wrong. ngDialog should have been injected into the directive definition:
Directive:

```
directives.directive('caseList', function (**ngDialog**) {
```

No need to inject it into Link function.